# Parallel for loop over numpy matrix

Tags: python-3.x, parallel-processing, python-multiprocessing, joblib, dtw

I am looking at the [`joblib`](https://pythonhosted.org/joblib/parallel.html) examples but I can't figure out how to do a parallel for loop over a matrix. I am computing a pairwise distance metric between the rows of a matrix. So I was doing:

```
N, _ = data.shape
upper_triangle = [(i, j) for i in range(N) for j in range(i + 1, N)]
dist_mat = np.zeros((N,N))  

for (i, j) in upper_triangle:
    dist_mat[i,j] = dist_fun(data[i], data[j])
    dist_mat[j,i] = dist_mat[i,j]
```

where `dist_fun` takes two vectors and computes a distance. How can I make this loop parallel since calls to `dist_fun` can be made independent of each other.

---

EDIT: The distance function I am using is [`fastdtw`](https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw) which is **not** so fast. So I think ***really do*** want to parallelize this. Using:

```
dist_mat = pdist(data, lambda x,y : fastdtw(x,y, dist=euclidean)[0])
```

I get an execution time of 58.1084 secs, and using:

```
dist_mat = np.zeros((N,N))
for (i,j), _ in np.ndenumerate(dist_mat):
    dist_mat[i,j], _ = fastdtw(data[i,:], timeseries[j,:], dist=euclidean)
```

I get 116.36 seconds and using:

```
upper_triangle = [(i,j) for i in range(N) for j in range(i+1, N)]
dist_mat = np.zeros((N,N))

for (i,j) in upper_triangle:
    dist_mat[i,j], _ = fastdtw(data[i,:], data[j,:], dist=euclidean)
    dist_mat[j,i] = dist_mat[i,j]
```

I get 55.62 secs. Here `N=33`. Does `scipy` automatically makes use of all available cores?

---

EDIT: I think I have found a work around using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/2/library/multiprocessing.html) package, but I will leave the question un-answered for the ***joblib*** folks to respond before I post what I think works.

Comment: [scipy.pdist()](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.spatial.distance.pdist.html) can be used for this

Comment: What's the typical N?

Comment: `data` is usually of size 33 x 300. So the `N` would be 33.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This can be done as follows using the [`multiprocessing`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/multiprocessing.html) module:

```
import numpy as np
from fastdtw import fastdtw
import multiprocessing as mp
from scipy.spatial.distance import squareform, euclidean
from functools import partial

# Create simulated data matrix
data = np.random.random((33,300))

N, _ = data.shape
upper_triangle = [(i,j) for i in range(N) for j in range(i+1, N)]

with mp.Pool(processes=4) as pool:
    result = pool.starmap(partial(fastdtw, dist=euclidean), [(data[i], data[j]) for (i,j) in upper_triangle])

dist_mat = squareform([item[0] for item in result])
```

Timing result using [`timeit`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/timeit.html) on an [IvyBridge Core-i5](https://ark.intel.com/products/65701/Intel-Core-i5-3570S-Processor-6M-Cache-up-to-3_80-GHz):

```
24.052 secs
```

which is half the time without explicit parallelization.

**ALSO:**

As a future reference for anyone using the [`fastdtw`](https://github.com/slaypni/fastdtw) package. Importing the distance functions from `scipy.spatial.distance` and calling `fastdtw` as shown in the example on the link is much slower than just using: `fastdtw(x,y,dist=2)`. The results seem similar to me and the execution time using `pdist` (without resorting to parallelization) is under a second.