# How to optimize this code having multiple loops?

Tags: python, numpy, loops, optimization

So i was trying this and I find it really unfeasible. I am not that aware about smart ways to do the following. Can somebody help ? Also inputs of lists are quite big.

This task was to create an image from the values generated by me.
center_star contains list of [x,y] pairs which are centers of various point like objects.

1800 value represents that image to be generated is of 1800x1800 pixel.

Sigma variable has value 2 by default.

```
final=[[0]*1800]*1800
for i in range(len(center_stars)):
    xi=center_stars[i][0]
    yi=center_stars[i][1]
    print(i)
    for j in range(1800):
        for k in range(1800):
            final[j][k]+=gauss_amplitude[i]*(math.e**((-1*((xi-j)**2+(yi-k)**2))/2*sigma*sigma))
```

Is there a smarter way to save time using some of the numpy operation and execute this piece of code in less time?

Comment: As a minor fix, save expressions that are repeatedly reused. `2*sigma*sigma` while small is recalculated every time through the loop. You should save this expression outside the loop over i. Similarly, in the loop over k, you recompute `(xi-j)**2` every iteration even though j isn't changing.

Comment: This looks like something to vectorize with `numpy`.

Comment: Some things you can check/read about: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11442191/parallelizing-a-numpy-vector-operation, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13068760/parallelise-python-loop-with-numpy-arrays-and-shared-memory, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350640/parallel-for-loop-over-numpy-matrix

Comment: All the 1800 elements of list `final` are the same lists!, changing `final[j][k]` in loop will change **ALL** `final[:][k]`s. Probably not what you intend. Definitely use numpy.

Comment: Btw, are you aware of that `a=[[0]*2]*2;a[0][0]=1;a[1][0]` displays `1`? The `*` creates multiple references to the same *object*, which is not a problem for an immutable number in 1D, but it is for a list for the 2nd dimension. Use list comprehensions instead, like `b=[[0 for i in range(2)] for j in range(2)];b[0][0]=1;b[1][0]`, which displays `0`.

Answer (score 0):

Something like that:

```
import math
import numpy as np
N = 1800
final = np.empty((N, N))
final1 = np.empty((N, N))
j = np.arange(N)
k = np.arange(N)
jj, kk = np.meshgrid(j, k)
sigma = 2.
s = 0.5 / (sigma * sigma)
for i in range(len(center_stars)):
    xi = center_stars[i][0]
    yi = center_stars[i][1]
    final += gauss_amplitude[i] * np.exp(- ((xi - jj.T)**2 + (yi - kk.T)**2) * s)
# Code below is for comparison:
    for j in range(N):
        for k in range(N):
            final1[j][k]+=gauss_amplitude[i] * (math.e** (-((xi-j)**2+(yi-k)**2)/(2*sigma*sigma)))
```

Besides, I assume you missed brackets around `2*sigma*sigma`

Comment: I tried this, and tried testing on center_star list with around 1400 elements it took around 250 seconds while for 2300 elements it took around 410 seconds. Is it possible to still optmize it ? My data-list is quite large.

Comment: You should obviously remove the last 4 lines from my example - they are just for comparison.

Comment: Also, if you need yet more speed, take a look at scipy.ndimage.convolve

Comment: ```final += gauss_amplitude[i] * np.exp(- ((xi - jj.T)**2 + (yi - kk.T)**2) * s)``` I changed this into ```final[x_min:x_max,y_min:y_max] += gauss_amplitude[i] * np.exp(- ((xs - jj.T[x_min:x_max,y_min:y_max]) ** 2 + (ys - kk.T[x_min:x_max,y_min:y_max]) ** 2) * s)```. This way I dont't have to do operation on such big meshgrid. I am calculating the x_max, x_min, y_max and y_min using width given by the user.

Answer (score 0):

you can try to compact your code like this:

```
Gauss=lambda i,j,k,xi,yi:gauss_amplitude[i]*(math.e**((-((xi-j)**2+(yi-k)**2))/(2*sigma*sigma)))
final=[[Gauss(i,j,k,x[0],x[1]) for j in range(1800) for k in range(1800)] for i,x in enumerate(center_starts)]
```

Comment: This only decreases the line of code. It still loops 1800*1800 times even in this list comprehension form. Its way slower than numpy.

Answer (score 0):

If your sigmas are all the same, you can achieve this with out any loop by using 
`scipy.signal.convolve2d`.

```py
import numpy as np
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from scipy.signal import convolve2d
from scipy.stats import multivariate_normal

sigma = 3
width = 200   # smaller than yours so you can see the single pixels
n_stars = 50

# draw some random stars
star_row = np.random.randint(0, width, n_stars)
star_col = np.random.randint(0, width, n_stars)
star_amplitude = np.random.normal(50, 10, n_stars)

# assign amplitudes to center pixel of stars
amplitudes = np.zeros((width, width))
amplitudes[star_row, star_col] = star_amplitude


# create 2d gaussian kernel
row = col = np.arange(-4 * sigma, 4 * sigma + 1)
grid = np.stack(np.meshgrid(row, col)).T
kernel = multivariate_normal(
    [0, 0],
    [[sigma**2, 0], [0, sigma**2]]
).pdf(grid)
kernel /= kernel.sum()


# convolve with 2d gaussian
final = convolve2d(amplitudes, kernel, mode='same')


fig, (ax1, ax2, ax3) = plt.subplots(1, 3, figsize=(9, 3))

img = ax1.imshow(amplitudes)
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax1)
ax1.set_label('Before Convolution')

img = ax2.imshow(kernel)
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax2)
ax2.set_label('Convolution Kernel')

img = ax3.imshow(final)
fig.colorbar(img, ax=ax3)
ax3.set_label('After Convolution')

fig.tight_layout()
fig.savefig('conv2d.png', dpi=300)
```

Result:

[image: result]

If the sigmas differ, you get a way with a single loop over the possible sigmas.

Comment: Image generated is all zero matrix using this code for my inputs

Comment: What are your Inputs then?

Comment: they won't fit here definately  @MaxNoe

Comment: One example should be enough to see why the output is exactly 0