# Filling out numpy array in parallel?

Tags: python, numpy, parallel-processing

I have code which looks something like this

```
import numpy as np
A = np.zeros((10000, 10))

for i in range(10000):

    # Some time-consuming calculations which result in a 10 element 1D array 'a'

    A[i, :] = a
```

How can I parallelize the `for` loop, so that the array `A` is filled out in parallel? My understanding is that multiple processes normally shouldn't be writing to the same variable, so it's not clear to me what the proper way of doing this is.

Comment: I would  just do `A = np.array([some_calculation(i) for i in range(len(A))])`.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parallel for loop over numpy matrix](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51350640/parallel-for-loop-over-numpy-matrix)

Comment: Collecting results in a list, and joining that into one array after might be the most robust approach.  Making an array from a list of array is relatively fast.  Whether this speeds things up depends on the complexity of the calculations compared to the multiprocessing speed.

Comment: Check out [`numba`](http://numba.pydata.org), they have good tools for parallelized writing to a single array.

Comment: Where do the calculations get their inputs from? Disk?

Answer (score 2):

This below code creates a thread for each line of the array, not sure how efficient it is though.

```py
import numpy as np
import threading

def thread_function(index, array):
  # aforementioned time-consuming calculation, resulting in 'a'
  a = np.ones(10)    # placeholder for calculation

  array[index, :] = a

if __name__ == "__main__":
  A = np.zeros((10000, 10))
  threads = []

  for i in range(10000):
    threads.append(threading.Thread(target=thread_function, args=(i, A)))
    threads[i].start()

  for i in range(10000):
    threads[i].join()

  print(A)
```

https://repl.it/@RobertClarke64/Python-Multithreading
As it is it's not particularly fast, but will hopefully be noticeably faster than running each calculation in series when the calculation takes a long time.

Answer (score 0):

Why not use the GPU's ability to do it in parallel:

```
import numpy as np
from numba import vectorize

@vectorize(["float32(float32, float32)"], target='cuda')
def f(a,b):

  for i in range(10000):
    a=4*b
  return a


a = np.ones((10000,10), dtype=np.float32)
b = np.random.rand(10000,10).astype('f')

f(a,b)
```